# I need to write a simulink s-function that is triggered by an input signal

Tags: simulink, eventtrigger, s-function

I wish to write data to a file when an integrator saturates.  I would like to route the integrator's saturation output port to one of the s-function's inputs.  I realize that I can continuously poll the signal, but I'd like to explore triggering on the signal.  In other words, for the s-function to behave similarly to a software interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Madison,

If you like to call s-function based on trigger, you might explore using a relational operator to check the condition. When the condition is True, function would be triggered.

Trying to embed a screenshot below:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch5A7.png)

Comment: Shafik M, your suggested approach works, and it is indeed what I am already doing.  The deficiency that I find is that the s-function samples the trigger during every sample interval whether or not the trigger is active.  If on the other hand the s-function is "activated" by the trigger, it is only called when there is data to be processed.  I am trying to streamline the execution of the model to increase execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

F. Madison,

If you like to trigger it on signal change from 0 to 1, you can make use of a condition made up of relational operator and Unit delay:

[Another Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71rlN.png)

Comment: Shafik M, once again your solution will work.  Though, it does so by polling input(s).  I suspect that this may be the best that can be done.  I was hoping to find a way for a signal to trigger an interrupt.